# jQuery autocomplete doesn't work with key value pair array

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I try to create an autocomplete field with jQuery autocomplete widget, but it seems that does not work for some reason.

The code I use is the following:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="specialties" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $specialties = [
    {
        id : 107,
        name : 'Painting'
    },
    {
        id : 158,
        name : 'Reading'
    }
];

var $specialty_text_field   =   $('#specialties');

$specialty_text_field.autocomplete(
    {
        source    : $specialties,
        minLength : 3
    }
);
```

And when I enter in the text field the text `Pain` I am getting as a result the text `No search results.`

What can be wrong with this code ?

Comment: any console errors???

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla no at all. My console is totally clear.

Comment: @NaveenThally This is what I try but I get a console error that I cannot figure out. Here is the fiddle URL (http://jsfiddle.net/ZQ9T3/). If somebody can help to fix the issue please?

Comment: You have both `#autocomplete` and `#specialties`, which should be?

Comment: your souce needs to ba an array cosisting of Strings. you are giving an array consisting of objects...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it is *clearly* stated in the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), your fields must be labeled `label` and `value`.

> **Array**: An array can be used for local data. There are two supported formats:
>
> ```
> An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
> An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
> ```

*EDIT* : And as it has been pointed out, the input's id is **autocomplete**, not **specialties**.

Comment: Thanks @Waldo Jeffers. That was the problem. Now it is working. I will mark your topic as the correct answer in a minute.

Comment: The text field id was wrong in stackoverflow. I just fixed this issue. In my local code this is correct :)